# Autolayout ignores multi-line detailTextLabel when calculating UITableViewCell height (all styles)

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

So I'm trying to use the built-in UITableViewCell styles - specifically UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle - with a (single) line **textLabel** but *multiline* **detailTextLabel**. But the (auto) calculated cell height is consistently too short, and appears to ignore that there is more than 1 line of detail.

I've tried using numberOfLines=0, estimatedRowHeight, UITableViewAutomaticDimension, preferredMaxWidthLayout, etc, but in all the permutations the behavior - indeed for *all* the UITableViewCell styles - is it appears the UITableViewAutomaticDimension cell height calculation will correctly account for a multiline **textLabel** (yay!), but incorrectly assumes the **detailTextlabel** is at most single line (nay!). Consequently, cells with a multiline detailTextLabel are too short, and hence the cell content spills over the top and bottom of the cell.

[image]

I've posted a quick test app showing this behavior on GitHub [here](https://github.com/tiritea/ios-uitableviewcelltest). Adding additional lines of text is fine - all the cell styles appropriately increase in height to accommodate - but adding additional lines of detail does nothing to change the cell height, and quickly causes the content to spill over; the text+detail are themselves laid out correctly, and together centered correctly over the middle of the cell (so in that sense layoutSubviews is working correctly), but the overall cell height itself is unchanged.

It almost seems like there are no actual top & bottom constraints between the cell.contentView and the labels, and instead the cell height is being calculated directly from the height of the (possibly multi-line) textLabel and (only single-line) detailTextLabel, and then everything is centered over the middle of the cell... Again, multiline textLabel is fine, and I'm doing nothing different between the textLabel and detailTextLabel, but only the former (correctly) adjusts the cell height.

So my question is, if it is possible to use the built-in UITableViewCell styles to reliably display *multiline* **detailTextLabels**, or is it simply not possible and you need to create a custom subclass instead? [or, almost equivalently, without having to override layoutSubviews in a subclass and rewire all the constraints manually].

---

[4 May 2016] Conclusion: as of iOS9 multi-line detailTextLabels dont work as expected with UITableViewAutomaticDimension; the cell will be consistently too short and the text/detail will spill over the top and bottom. Either you must manually compute the correct cell height yourself, or create and layout your own equivalent custom UITableViewCell subclass, or (see my answer below) subclass UITableViewCell and fix `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:` to return the correct height [recommended]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Further investigations (see [UITableViewCellTest](https://github.com/tiritea/UITableViewCellTest)) indicate that when *UITableViewAutomaticDimension* is enabled the system calls `-systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:` to calculate the cell height, and that this pretty much ignores the height of the detailTextLabel in its computation (bug !?). As a result, for *UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle* the cell height is always going to be too short [a single-line **detailTextLabel** may not quite spill over the cell, but that's only because of the existing top and bottom margins], and for *UITableViewCellStyleValue1* or *UITableViewCellStyleValue2* the height will be too short whenever the **detailTextLabel** is taller (eg more lines) than the **textLabel**. This is all a moot point for *UITableViewCellStyleDefault* which has no detailTextLabel.

My solution was to subclass and fix with:

```
- (CGSize)systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:(CGSize)targetSize
        withHorizontalFittingPriority:(UILayoutPriority)horizontalFittingPriority
              verticalFittingPriority:(UILayoutPriority)verticalFittingPriority
{
    // Bug finally fixed in iOS 11
    if ([UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion compare:@"11" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        return [super systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:targetSize
                    withHorizontalFittingPriority:horizontalFittingPriority
                          verticalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority];
    }

    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    CGSize size = [super systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:targetSize
                       withHorizontalFittingPriority:horizontalFittingPriority
                             verticalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority];
    CGFloat detailHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.detailTextLabel.frame);
    if (detailHeight) { // if no detailTextLabel (eg style = Default) then no adjustment necessary
        // Determine UITableViewCellStyle by looking at textLabel vs detailTextLabel layout
        if (CGRectGetMinX(self.detailTextLabel.frame) > CGRectGetMinX(self.textLabel.frame)) { // style = Value1 or Value2
            CGFloat textHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.textLabel.frame);
            // If detailTextLabel taller than textLabel then add difference to cell height
            if (detailHeight > textHeight) size.height += detailHeight - textHeight;
        } else { // style = Subtitle, so always add subtitle height
            size.height += detailHeight;
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

And in the view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

You can pull the full subclass from here: [MultilineTableViewCell](https://github.com/tiritea/MultilineTableViewCell)

So far this fix appears to work well, and has let me successfully use the built-in UITableViewCellStyles with **multiline** text and details, in self-sizing cells with dynamic type support. This avoids the trouble (and mess) of manually computing the desired cell heights in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, or having to create custom cell layouts.

**[(PARTLY)FIXED IN iOS11]**

Apple *finally* fixed this bug in iOS11 (but apparantly only for UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle). I've updated my solution to only apply the necessary correction to pre-11 devices (otherwise you'll end up with *extra* space top and bottom of your cell!).

Comment: I've been using some code based closesly on this answer for a while and realised recently that it didn't seem to be working correctly when used in a TableView presented modally. The problem was that 'detailHeight' was being returned as zero.

I found that adding [self layoutIfNeeded] at the beginning of the function solved the issue.

Comment: Cheers. I'd also noticed that sometimes the cell height was still too short the very _first_ time the cell was shown, but then it would magically fix itself shortly thereafter (eg rotating the display). As you say, adding [self layoutIfNeeded] does the trick, thanks!

Comment: iOS 11 adds double space here.

Comment: This solution worked for a table view I called from a controller I called programmatically, but I can't get it to work (so far) using a controller set up in the storyboard. I'm probably just missing a storyboard setting somewhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: Victor - make sure in the storyboard GUI that you are populating your tableview with the this custom UITableViewCell *subclass*; if you drag-n-drop UITableViewCells in the GUI you'll populate it with just the regular (broken) iOS UITableViewCells

Comment: Are you *sure* this is fixed for Value1 cells in iOS 11??? I find that this is very much needed even in iOS 11.2 unfortunately!

Answer (score 5):

@tiritea 's answer in Swift 3 (Thanks again! :D)

```
// When UITableViewAutomaticDimension is enabled the system calls 
// -systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority: to calculate the cell height.
// Unfortunately, it ignores the height of the detailTextLabel in its computation (bug !?). 
// As a result, for UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle the cell height is always going to be too short.
// So we override to include detailTextLabel height.
// Credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37016869/467588
override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
  self.layoutIfNeeded()
  var size = super.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: horizontalFittingPriority, verticalFittingPriority: verticalFittingPriority)
  if let textLabel = self.textLabel, let detailTextLabel = self.detailTextLabel {
    let detailHeight = detailTextLabel.frame.size.height
    if detailTextLabel.frame.origin.x > textLabel.frame.origin.x { // style = Value1 or Value2
      let textHeight = textLabel.frame.size.height
      if (detailHeight > textHeight) {
        size.height += detailHeight - textHeight
      }
    } else { // style = Subtitle, so always add subtitle height
      size.height += detailHeight
    }
  }
  return size
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Apple has resolved this bug in iOS 11.

Comment: Lets hope so. I'm surprised something in iOS as fundamental as UITableViewCells with Autolayout can remain broken for so long...

Comment: I find that it is fixed for Subtitle cells but not Value1 cells in iOS 11.

Comment: Looks like this got fixed in iOS11.x for some styles (Subtitle) but not others (Value1). Geez, c'mon Apple, get with the program :-(

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

After reading various answers, I have used following method for get ride of detail text label UITableViewAutomaticDimension issue . Use Basic style cell with title label only and use attributed string for Text and detail text view. Don't forget to Change tableview cell style from Subtitle to Basic.

```
func makeAttributedString(title: String, subtitle: String) -> NSAttributedString {
let titleAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.purple]
let subtitleAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)]

let titleString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(title)\n", attributes: titleAttributes)
let subtitleString = NSAttributedString(string: subtitle, attributes: subtitleAttributes)

titleString.append(subtitleString)

return titleString
}
```

How to use in cellforrowatindexpath

```
cell.textLabel?.attributedText = makeAttributedString(title: "Your Title", subtitle: "Your detail text label text here")
```

Add Following lines in viewdidload

```
    YourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    YourTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    YourTableView.setNeedsLayout()
    YourTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Using an single attributed string broken across two lines, and applying different attributes to the two substrings in an attempt to replicate iOS's default textLabel vs detailTextLabel styles, is a kludge. It is also only useful for trying to mimic the Subtitle style; its of no use for fixing the problem for Value1 or Value2 styles.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience the built in cells don't  support auto resize with constraints, I think the best solution is to create a custom cell, it really takes a couple of minutes and you don't need to override layoutSubview, it is really simple .
Just change the type of the cell in the IB to custom, drag a label , set constraints (in the IB), set number of rows , create a subclass, change the cells class in the IB to your subclass, create an outlet in the subclass and that's most of the work, 
I am sure there are a lot of tutorials on the net you can follow.

Comment: Creating a custom cell isn't a problem, or challenge. Rather, I want to maximize the built-in functionality of iOS and not unnecessarily re-invent a wheel; what the existing UITableViewCellStyle's do they do extremely well. But the UITableViewAutomaticDimension appears to be broken for multi-line *detailTextLabels*. Before resorting to re-implementing the UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle style just to handle 2 or 3 lines of subtitle I want to confirm there isn't some 'trick' I've missed. Or if this is an undocumented feature (ie will never be fixed). Or a bug (ie should be reported and fixed).

Comment: There is no trick , you can't change the layout of predefined content like the default textLabel detailTextLabel and imageView, if you set the estimatedRowHeight to some height and the rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension and it has no effect on the default labels and this is how they work since earlier iOS systems then it's not a bug and there is no trick, maybe it will change in the future and may be it won't , but a practical and fast solution is to use custom cells.

Comment: You could add this tutorial link to your answer: http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/