# UITableViewAutomaticDimension applied on subtitle table view cell not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making one view for the listing. It has dynamic length in subtitle. So i used UITableViewAutomaticDimension properties. I have not applied any constraint because both the label are table view cell properties so no need to make new custom cell.

But after running this project i marked that UITableViewAutomaticDimension not working properly. I don't know what i doing wrong. My code is like below

> view did load

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblabc: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tblabc.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        tblabc.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        tblabc.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

> table view delegate and data source

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
        if (cell == nil)
        {

            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            cell?.selectionStyle = .None
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.font = _SETREGULARFONT_KARLA(IS_IPAD ? 19:15)
            cell?.textLabel?.font = _SETBOLDFONT_KARLA(IS_IPAD ? 17:13)
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.textColor = getColorFromRGB(120, G: 132, B: 158, A: 1.0)
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
            cell?.selectionStyle = .None

        }

        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Testing" + "\(indexPath.row)"
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "tesfhjdsfskdfhjkfhdjskfhsjkdfhdjsxdfgfjljkgjfklgfhsdjfhjkdshfdjskfhdjfjkfhafyhdsifjhdjksfbshdjkfkhdksjfhdjsfyhds8ufdhsfjkhdsfjhdfudsiufhdsfh"
        cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "new_temp")

        return cell!
    }
```

> View looks like below image

[image]

Comment: Please refer to below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587126/autolayout-ignores-multi-line-detailtextlabel-when-calculating-uitableviewcell-h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Modify code :-

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
    if (cell == nil)
    {

        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell?.selectionStyle = .None
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.font = _SETREGULARFONT_KARLA(IS_IPAD ? 19:15)
        cell?.textLabel?.font = _SETBOLDFONT_KARLA(IS_IPAD ? 17:13)
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.textColor = getColorFromRGB(120, G: 132, B: 158, A: 1.0)
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
        cell?.selectionStyle = .None

    }

    cell?.textLabel?.text = "Testing" + "\(indexPath.row)"
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "tesfhjdsfskdfhjkfhdjskfhsjkdfhdjsxdfgfjljkgjfklgfhsdjfhjkdshfdjskfhdjfjkfhafyhdsifjhdjksfbshdjkfkhdksjfhdjsfyhds8ufdhsfjkhdsfjhdfudsiufhdsfh"
    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "new_temp")

    return cell!
}
```

Please remove the HeightForRowAtIndex datasource Method.

Answer (score 3):

The UITableViewAutomaticDimension height calculation for the built-in UITableViewCellStyles (all of them!) is basically 'broken' when you have a *multi-line* detailTextLabel. As Venkat Reddy commented, see my solution here: [Autolayout ignores multi-line detailTextLabel when calculating UITableViewCell height (all styles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587126/autolayout-ignores-multi-line-detailtextlabel-when-calculating-uitableviewcell-h)

[Someone with suitable privileges should consider flagging this question as a duplicate]

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be fixed in iOS 11. A shortcut solution working just fine on lower versions is to fake the desired subtitle appearance within a Basic cell by setting its textlabel.attributedText to have a bolder first line(s) + \n + regular more lines.

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

remove both line:

```
tblabc.estimatedRowHeight = 44
tblabc.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: The estimatedRowHeight is not supposed to be UITableViewAutomaticDimension, it's supposed to be a real number to help the system figure out an estimate for the row height before the autolayout determines a dynamic row height.