# UITableViewCell style subtitle mutiple line not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I have one custom style `UITableviewCell` and it have default height for other I am using tableview cell with style of subtitle and I want to make subtitle to be multiple lines. And it's doing good but having problem with calculating tableview cell height and I use `UITableviewAutomaticDimension` but its not working.

**Here is my code**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(indexPath.row==0){
        var cell: ImageCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageCell") as? ImageCell
        if cell == nil {
            tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ImageCell" ,bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell")
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageCell") as? ImageCell
        }
        return cell
    }else{

        var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SubtitleCell")
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "SubtitleCell")
            cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
            cell!.textLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 15)
            cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            cell!.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            cell!.selectedBackgroundView = UIView.init()
        }
        cell!.textLabel?.text = "TExt"
        cell!.detailTextLabel!.text="Keep in mind that UITableView is defined as an optional in the function, which means your initial cell declaration needs to check for the optional in the property. Also, the returned queued cell is also optional, so ensure you make an optional cast to UITableViewCell. Afterwards, we can force unwrap because we know we have a cell."
        allowMultipleLines(cell!)
        cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "IconProfile")

        return cell!
    }
}
func allowMultipleLines(tableViewCell:UITableViewCell) {
    tableViewCell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    tableViewCell.detailTextLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if(indexPath.row==0){
        return 172
    }else{
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587126/autolayout-ignores-multi-line-detailtextlabel-when-calculating-uitableviewcell-h

Answer (score 0):

in your viewDidLoad() Method you need to write

```
yourTableViewName.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

And Add One more method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if(indexPath.row==0){
        return 172
    }else{
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }
}
```

i hope this will help you

Comment: you are using auto layout?

Comment: Yes autolayout is checked.

Comment: just comment heightForRowAtIndexPath method and run you project

Comment: No it is not working for subtitle multiline.It just return around 45 for each row height.