# cell text label not centered after changing the cell height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a value1 type of cell, because some of my detailed label text is too long and getting truncated, so I am updating the cell height to fit the text.

However after updating the height, my text label is at the top left corner instead of vertically being in the middle. So like this:

```
==================         =====================
label                =>    label
==================         

                           =====================
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit**

Code for change height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var rowHeight=44.0
    var numOfLines = 1;
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath),let label = cell.detailTextLabel, let size = label.text?.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:label.font]){
        let labelWidth = label.frame.width
        label.textAlignment = .left
        while(Int(size.width) > Int(labelWidth) * numOfLines){
            rowHeight+=20;
            numOfLines+=1
        }
        //becuase it was rounded down as int
        numOfLines+=1
        print("number of lines \(numOfLines)")
        label.numberOfLines = numOfLines
        label.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
    }
    return CGFloat(rowHeight)
}
```

Comment: show how you set the constraints

Comment: @Sh_Khan updated

Comment: Do not get the cell in `heightForRowAt`. There is no need. Get the text from the data model, not the cell.

Comment: @rmaddy I need the cell because I need the label dimension for that cell to update the height.

Answer (score 0):

@Anna, I believe your problem can be resolved with **`UITableViewAutomaticDimension`**.

Just make sure the `numberOfLines` for the label is set to `0` and the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method should return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` as well as do not forget to add right, left, top & bottom constraints for the label.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }
```

Please find the link for more reference:
[UITableViewAutomaticDimension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewautomaticdimension?language=occ)

Comment: automatic dimension only works for subtitle type's detailed label not value1 and value2 type. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587126/autolayout-ignores-multi-line-detailtextlabel-when-calculating-uitableviewcell-h